# Попадает ли дата в промежуток дат .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime

Есть две даты типа `System.DateTime` каким (наиболее правильным) методом можно проверить, входит ли третья дата типа `System.DateTime` в промежуток между ними?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsInRange(this DateTime dateToCheck, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return dateToCheck >= startDate && dateToCheck < endDate;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
DateTime dateToCheck = DateTime.Now;
dateToCheck.IsInRange(startDate, endDate)
```

> Перед сравнением DateTime объектов, убедитесь, что они представляют
>   время в том же часовом поясе. ([подробнее](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_greaterthan(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Не думал что даты можно так сравнивать...

Comment: А почему только меньше верхнего диапазона, а не меньше или равно?

Comment: включать или нет верхний диапазон это на ваше усмотрение. еще такой момент, даты должны быть в одном часовом поясе